# Warning: Converting non-floating point data to single

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, feature-extraction

I've been working with feature extraction and epipolar geometry. However, I'm constantly coming across the the following error:

> Warning: Converting non-floating point data to single. 
>   In pdist2 (line 219)
>   In extractFeaturesU (line 93)

The code line that is returning a warning message is:

```
[distance, position] = sort(pdist2(double(repmat(featuresA, size(xPoints, 1))), featuresB), 2, 'ascend');
```

The part of the code containing the above line is displayed below.

```
%% extract features
corresponding = [];
rightBound = size(sharpImageB, 2);
xPoints = 3 : 3 : rightBound - 3;
for index = 1 : size(realWantedPoints, 2) 
    %extract features from wanted points
    disp('extracting features from wanted points...');   
    if strcmp(desc, 'hog')
        [featuresA, pointsA] = extractHOGFeatures(sharpImageA, realWantedPoints(:, index)', ...
        'CellSize', [8 8], 'BlockSize', [2 2], 'NumBins', 9, 'UseSignedOrientation', true);
    elseif strcmp(desc, 'block')
        [featuresA, pointsA] = extractFeatures(sharpImageA, realWantedPoints(:, index)', ...
        'Method', 'Block', 'BlockSize', 21, 'Upright', true);
    elseif strcmp(desc, 'surf')
        [featuresA, pointsA] = extractFeatures(sharpImageA, realWantedPoints(:, index)', ...
        'Method', 'SURF', 'SURFSize', 64, 'Upright', true);
    end

    % generate epipolar line points
    liner = star([1 0 0]) * [realWantedPoints(:, index); 1];
    yPoints = -(liner(3) + (liner(1) * xPoints)) / liner(2);
    matrixB = [xPoints', yPoints'];

    % extract features from epipolar line points
    disp('extracting features from epipolar line points...');   
    if strcmp('hog', desc)
        [featuresB, pointsB] = extractHOGFeatures(sharpImageB, matrixB, ...
        'CellSize', [8 8], 'BlockSize', [2 2], 'NumBins', 9, 'UseSignedOrientation', true);
    elseif strcmp('block', desc)
        [featuresB, pointsB] = extractFeatures(sharpImageB, matrixB, ...
        'Method', 'Block', 'BlockSize', 21, 'Upright', true);
    elseif strcmp('surf', desc)
        [featuresB, pointsB] = extractFeatures(greyB, matrixB, ...
        'Method', 'SURF', 'SURFSize', 64, 'Upright', true);
    end

    % calculate similarity
    [distance, position] = sort(pdist2(double(repmat(featuresA, size(xPoints, 1))), featuresB), 2, 'ascend');
    corresponding = [corresponding; pointsB(position(1), :)];
end

xB = corresponding(:, 1);
yB = corresponding(:, 2);
```

Comment: What's the data type of featuresB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can generate that error by calling `pdist2` on two variables: one of type double and one of type single. Eg.

```
x = ones(5,1,'single');
y = ones(5,1,'double');
pdist2(x,y);
```

My guess is that your `featuresB` variable is single precision floating point and hence doesn't match the type of your first argument to pdist2 (which is double because you explicitly convert it).